# Automapper not copy list object to another

Tags: c#, automapper, .net-4.5.2

I have list of my class type which I need to copy to another class type. In following code I am trying to copy GenderEntity to Gender but getting no results

```
private void MapGender()
    {
        List<GenderEntity> _GenderEntity = _GenderServiceObject.GenderEntity();

        List<Gender> _Gender = new List<Gender>();

        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<List<GenderEntity>, List<Gender>>();
        });

        IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        _Gender = mapper.Map<List<GenderEntity>, List<Gender>>(_GenderEntity);

        var x = "d";
    }
```

### GenderEntity - Source

```
public class GenderEntity
{
    public GenderEntity() { }

    public string Code { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

}
```

### Gender - Destination

```
 [DataContract]
public class Gender
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Gender entity is used for WCF SOAP services as data contract

### Return List Class

```
 public class GenderService
{

    #region EBS Service return 'Gender'  
    public Gender GenderEBSEntity()
    {
        return GenderEBS.GetGender_EBS();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Mapped Gender Entity
    public List<GenderEntity> GenderEntity()
    {        
           return GenderEBS.GetGenderEntity();            
    }
    #endregion

}
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my answer...

```
 private void MapGender()
    {
       List<Gender> MappedGender = new List<Contracts.Data.Gender>();

       IList<GenderEntity> genderEntity = _GenderServiceObject.GenderEntity();

        if(genderEntity!=null)
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<GenderEntity, Gender>();
            });

            IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();

            gender = mapper.Map<IList<GenderEntity>, IList<Gender>>(genderEntity).ToList();

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to map Lists with AutoMapper, just create a map like:

```
cfg.CreateMap<GenderEntity, Gender>();
```

and then map it like this:

```
 _Gender = mapper.Map<Gender[]>(_GenderEntity).ToList();
```